# What is known about the internal workings of the Z80?

Tags: z80, reverse-engineering

There is a wonderful project called [Visual6502](http://www.visual6502.org/), and I've used it from time to time to figure things out, like exactly the difference between `rti` and `rts`. It is good to see which control lines were fired in each cycle from the Control ROM.

But Z80 is a whole other thing. It's not microcoded like the 6502 is, but instead apparently contains some finite state machines and things. I am not sure I understand why that design choice was made, especially considering the relatively more complex ISA, including variable-length instruction codes. But I really have no idea about that.

So I am interested in finding out more about how the Z80 worked. Has this chip been reverse-engineered and had its internal mechanisms explained, such that it can be understood by laypeople?

Comment: I am especially interested in the parts which decode instructions. My guess is that prefixes modify some kind of internal state, and all other instructions reset that state, but it would be interesting to find out more.

Comment: _(Not enough for an answer)_ You may want do browse thru [Ken Shirriff's Blog](http://www.righto.com/) as he describes quite some internals for 8080/8085/Z80. (I think he's as well on RC.SE)

Comment: More specific link: [posts tagged "Z-80" on Ken's blog](http://www.righto.com/search/label/Z-80)

Comment: The 6502 is not microcoded - it uses a PLA to decode and execute instructions.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru What do you call the data on the PLA then? Microcode is as good a term as any.

Comment: PLA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_array
Microcode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode
tl;dr A PLA is a piece of hardware designed to route electrical signals in a particular way to generate particular outputs for given inputs. The 6502 uses this technology to implement opcodes.
Microcode is a software construct written against the hardware to implement higher-level assembler op-codes. The x86 family use this technology.
They are not the same, and to call the 6502 architecture a microcoded implementation is incorrect.

Comment: An important thing to note about PLAs during the NMOS era is that many chips had only a single layer of metal, in addition to the polysilicon layer that could be used to route signals for short distances.  Consequently, most of the space on a chip would be occupied not by transistors, but by wires connecting them.  A PLA uses more transistors than would be needed to accomplish the same task with direct-wired logic, but minimizes the routing space between the transistors, sometimes offering a huge win.

Answer (score 9):

Z80 has been implemented in the Visual6502 way too. However looks like the site `http://www.micrologo.net/z80x` is no longer operational. It was Z80 die simulation in Javascript When I searched matching stuff from mine off-line copy I found this repository:

- [Visual6502 Z80 chipsim](https://github.com/trebonian/visual6502)

So if you want to run the Z80 simulation, either [use the online version](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert-z80.html) or download the repo and open `expert-z80.html` file from it in your browser.

Yes a lot has been reversed especially the 4bit ALU of Z80. See **Ken Shirriff's blog** sites are really good and I used them while perfected my Z80 emulator:

- [Down to the silicon: how the Z80's registers are implemented](http://www.righto.com/2014/10/how-z80s-registers-are-implemented-down.html)
- [The Z-80 has a 4-bit ALU. Here's how it works](http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html)

I ended up with this ISET configuration:

- [SO/SE: What's the proper implementation for hardware emulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911590/2521214)

Which breaks down all the instructions into their machine cycles ... Once you done that many things start to be obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The best I've seen is [Goran Devic's implementation](http://baltazarstudios.com/z80-cpu/) for an FPGA.  He's taken the existing bits of Z-80 reverse engineering and filled in the missing pieces and connected them all together.  Read through the blog and you'll find a large PNG functional diagram and a link to a [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/gdevic/a-z80/src/master/) of all the code.

Although I haven't done a deep dive into the details, it does seem to be similar to the 6502 in that a PLA is used to decode instructions and drive various sub-circuits.  It does differ at the low level in a lot of ways in how the register files and ALUs are implemented.